# How to get Google's colab "local connection settings" working? (Connect is grayed out)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, jupyter, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to get Google COLAB to connect to a local docker image running tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter.

I can connect directly to the instance as "http://192.168.1.130:8888?token=XXXXX" but when I insert said backend URL into the "local connection settings" dialog the "connect" button remains disabled.

I have tried both Firefox and Chrome.

The javascript console does not show any errors or connection attemps (xhr or ws) to the container's IP address.

The docker image has jupyter_http_over_ws installed and enabled.

The notebook is running with allow_origin='*' right now.

The Dockerfile CMD entry:

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "source /etc/bash.bashrc && jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/tf --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root --NotebookApp.allow_origin='*'"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the IP address to be 'localhost' within the URL appears to aid enabling the *Connect* button.

e.g.
`http://192.168.1.130:8888?token=XXXXX` becomes `http://localhost:8888?token=XXXXX`

Comment: Trying to connect to the remote host 192.168.1.130 is not accomplished by replacing it with "localhost" (aka 127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

No, the ip address is not allowed here and you must use localhost.

I believe this is for security reason from Google.